# (Prove or Disprove) A sequence of integral kernels (from quantum mechanics) approaches to delta function (in the distribution sense)?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I can prove the following fact, for $\forall f \in S(\mathbb{R})$, where $S(\mathbb{R})$ means the Schwartz space,

${\displaystyle \lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0^+}} {\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \pi \tau}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \tau}} f(x) dx = f(0)$.

The question is, when I change the $\tau$ in the above formula to $it$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$, does the changed formula hold?

${\displaystyle \lim_{t \rightarrow 0}} {\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}}} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \pi i t}} e^{i\frac{x^2}{2 t}} f(x) dx = f(0)$.

The issue here is that when $t$ approaches to zero, we can not let the integral of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \pi i t}} e^{i\frac{x^2}{2 t}}$ outside a fixed neighborhood of the zero point approaches to zero.

So, does the changed formula hold? If it does, how to prove this? If it doesn't, can we construct a function $f\in S(\mathbb{R})$ that breaks the equality?

Comment: Can you give a counterexample or explain in more detail why it is not true?

Comment: To me, it is not obvious that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \int_{| x | >\delta} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi i t}} e^{i \frac{x^2}{2t}} dx \neq 0$. Since if we let $y = \frac{x}{\sqrt{t}}$, the integral becomes $\int_{|y|>\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{t}}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi i}} e^{i \frac{y^2}{2}} dy$. Since $\int_{\mathbb{R}} cos(y^2) dy = \sqrt{\pi / 2}$, maybe it do approaches to zero?

Comment: Why it must larger than zero?

Comment: @Herman. The factor $f(x)$ makes the integral convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\epsilon>0,\ t>0$ let $u_{\epsilon,t} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be defined by
$$
u_{\epsilon,t}(x) 
:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi i t}} e^{(i-\epsilon)x^2/(2t)}
.
$$

This function satisfies the differential equation
$
u_{\epsilon,t}'(x)
= \frac{(i-\epsilon)}{t} x \, u_{\epsilon,t}(x)
.
$
Taking the Fourier transform of both sides gives
$
i\xi \, \hat{u}_{\epsilon,t}(\xi)
= i\frac{(i-\epsilon)}{t} \, \hat{u}_{\epsilon,t}'(\xi)
,
$
i.e.
$$
\hat{u}_{\epsilon,t}'(\xi)
= t\frac{\xi}{i-\epsilon} \hat{u}_{\epsilon,t}(\xi)
.
$$

Thus,
$
\hat{u}_{\epsilon,t}(\xi)
= C_{\epsilon,t} e^{-t(\epsilon+i)\xi^2/(2(1+\epsilon^2))}
,
$
where
$$
C_{\epsilon,t}
= \hat{u}_{\epsilon,t}(0)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi i t}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{(i-\epsilon)x^2/(2t)} \, dx
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+i\epsilon}}
.
$$

Letting $\epsilon\to 0$ we get
$
\hat{u}_{0,t}(\xi)
= e^{-it\xi^2/2}
.
$
Now we see that $\hat{u}_{0,t}(\xi) \to 1 = \hat{\delta}(\xi)$ as $t \to 0$. From this we conclude that $u_{0,t} \to \delta$ as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Sorry for my little mistake. Good that it didn't confuse you too much, and that you fixed it.